# Why does a circular loop in an external magnetic field when released flip over?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image]

A current-carrying loop of wire is placed in a uniform external magnetic field as shown. If the current in the wire is traveling counterclockwise in the picture, what do you predict the loop will do when released?

The answer provided for this question: From the RHR for loops, place the heel of the right hand in the plane of the loop so that the fingers are curled in the direction of  the current. The extended thumb points in the direction of the B-field. Since it is anti-parallel to the external B-field, the loop will flip over and then remain at rest.

I don't understand what causes that. When you apply the Right-Hand Rule or Flaming Left-hand Rule I prefer, the force induced is inward around the loop. How come it makes it flip over? I must be missing something deep here.

What is the underlying concept that causes the wire to flip over?

Comment: Don't they cancel each other as they are outward all around the loop?

Comment: The current in the loop creates a magnetic dipole μ = IA. You are looking at the interaction of this dipole with the external field.

Comment: Can you please expand on it? How does this interaction of the dipoles make it flip over?

Comment: The energy of a dipole $\mu$ in a field $B$ is $E = -\mu\cdot\mathrm B$. So the lowest energy state is when the dipole and the field point in the same direction. In your diagram the dipole and field point in opposite directions so that's the _highest_ energy state.

Comment: Then that explains why the loop flips over? How does this torque arise?

Comment: As drawn, the loop is in an unstable equilibrium. There is no torque on it when it is exactly normal to the field, but the slightest deviation will cause a torque that will make it flip over.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I want to dive deep into that magnetic moment and unstable equilibrium concept. It seems like I've never been introduced. Do you have any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: After editing, the question does not make sense. There is no indication of the direction of the current in the loop. Does the loop flips over no matter which way the current goes? If it were so, it will continue to flip over forever.

Comment: Should not reopen until the statement of the problem makes sense and does not contain unsupported statements like "it is said that a current-carrying loop..."

Comment: @nasu I edited the question. Review please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is poorly phrased but it's getting at something interesting.

You're correct that all the forces on the various pieces of the wire cancel out, but note that they point *inwards* rather than outwards.  This means that the loop is in an equilibrium state.

However, this equilibrium state is an unstable equilibrium.  Imagine that the loop was perturbed ever so slightly, rotated by a very small angle about a vertical axis in the plane of the paper.  In other words, the  right side of the loop is slightly above the plane of the paper, and the left side of the loop is slightly below.  If this happens, the net force on the right side of the loop will point to the left;  and the net force on the left side of the loop points to the right.  For both sides, there is a torque on the wire that will tend to rotate the loop *further* out of the plane.  So unless the loop is *perfectly* placed perpendicularly to the magnetic field, it will not stay in that configuration.

In contrast, let's suppose that the loop is flipped over, so that the current is now flowing clockwise in the plane.  A similar argument will show that a small perturbation out of the plane will cause a *restoring* torque that tends to push it back into the plane.  In other words, a clockwise current is stable for a magnetic field into the page, while a counter-clockwise current is unstable.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: Just for completeness: when the loop flips over it typically first overshoots a bit and then oscillates until it settles in flipped orientation. This overshooting is reduced by friction and viscosity. In the absence of friction and viscosity the loop will carry on flipping back and forth, a bit like the oscillation of a pendulum or a spring in the absence of friction.

Comment: It's like a coil of wire in an external magnetic field. It keeps rotating as the current changes direction due to split ring commutators. It keeps flipping over because of its momentum gained before. After each turn current changes direction from clockwise to counterclockwise or vice versa. Hope I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the B field due to the current in the wire says nothing about the force on the wire.  The force per unit length on a wire with a current I in a B field is given by
${\bf F}/L={\bf I\times B}$.  This force is towards the center of the circle at every point on the wire, so nothing will flip.